# Parallel FileEnumeration incl Top Directory

Tags: c#

I was looking to speed up directory enumeration and discovered a nice snippet below.

```
FileInfo[] files= dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
            .AsParallel()
            .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray();
```

My problem is this doesn't appear to return files in the top directory so I ended up adding;

```
FileInfo[] files2 = dirInfo.GetFiles();
```

...and combining the arrays.

I was wondering if there is a better way to collect all the fileInfos at once, including the top directory,  while still capitalising on the AsParallel()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                   .AsParallel()
                   .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                   .ToArray()
                   .Union(dirInfo.EnumerateFiles())
                   .ToArray();
```